# mod_evasive is not blocking IPs causing DoS, but is logging them

Tags: apache, freebsd, ddos, mod-evasive

mod_evasive is not blocking IPs that are causing DoS, but it is logging the IPs in the `/tmp` directory. The files it generates to this directory are named `dos-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` (`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` being the IP). The OS is FreeBSD.

Have read that mod_evasive does not work well with the mpm_prefork_module because it uses processes over threads. This is not being used, but mpm_event_module is (not mpm_worker_module). Not sure if this is the problem?

Here is the content of the mod_evasive config file created at `/usr/local/etc/apache24/Includes/mod_evasive.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
    DOSHashTableSize 3097
    DOSPageCount 2
    DOSPageInterval 1
    DOSSiteCount 50
    DOSSiteInterval 1
    DOSBlockingPeriod 60
    DOSEmailNotify example@example.com
</IfModule>
```

Have also read that mod_evasive uses iptables, but ipfw is being used. Again, I'm not sure if this is the issue?

Also noticed a trend of `sudo` privileges being given to Apache in some of the examples found online (particularly when using mod_evasive's `DOSSystemCommand`). I don't intend to give Apache `sudo` privileges, but have tried adding deny directives to ipfw using `DOSSystemCommand` with `sudo` privileges:

```
DOSSystemCommand "sudo ipfw add 00010 deny ip from %s to any"
```

This also didn't end well. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you try a suitable mailing list https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/eresources-mail.html people are much more active there than on SO.

Comment: mod_evasive doesn't use `iptables` or `ipfw`. It can launch any command using the `DOSSystemCommand` directive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be using mod evasive in version 2.0 for apache version 2.4. You need a newer version of mod evasive. There is 2.4 version source code available.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you installed it properly,

**#pkg search mod_evasive**

ap24-mod_evasive-1.10.1_1 Apache module to try to protect the HTTP Server from DoS/DDoS attacks

**#pkg install ap24-mod_evasive-1.10.1_1**

Now open the mod_evasive configuration,

**sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/evasive.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
DOSHashTableSize    3097
DOSPageCount        2
DOSSiteCount        50
DOSPageInterval     1
DOSSiteInterval     1
DOSBlockingPeriod   10
#DOSEmailNotify      you@yourdomain.com
#DOSSystemCommand    "su - someuser -c '/sbin/... %s ...'"
DOSLogDir           "/var/log/mod_evasive"
</IfModule>
```

Create the directory

**sudo mkdir /var/log/mod_evasive**

Now whitelist the IPs you want, inside the configuration

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
DOSWhitelist 127.0.0.1
</IfModule>
```

Now enable the evasive module and restart the apache

**sudo a2enmod evasive**

**sudo service apache2 restart**

Now you can check the blocked IPs in the below location

**cd /var/log/mod_evasive**

Also, you can check the Blacklisted IPs by checking the apache status

**sudo service apache2 status**